# How can I get the clicked div in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm doing a little whack-a-mole game in JavaScript and I don't know how can I get the div clicked. I explain:

I got this index html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <main>
        <div id="top">
            <p class="blue_button" id="points">points</p>
            <p id="beauty_text">Whack-a-mole</p>
            <p class="blue_button" id="lifes">lifes</p>
        </div>
        <div id="meteors">
            <img src="asteroid.png" class="asteroid">
            <img src="asteroid.png" class="asteroid">
            <img src="asteroid.png" class="asteroid">
            <br>
            <img src="asteroid.png" class="asteroid">
            <img src="asteroid.png" class="asteroid">
        </div>
        <div>
            <button class="blue_button" onclick="startGame();">Start</button>
        </div>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

And, this JavaScript (I know I got some problems catching the elements, in the queryselector, etc. But that's not important (for now):

```js
function startGame(){
    //Aquí declaro las variables que voy a usar
    let lifes = document.getElementById('lifes');
    const points = document.getElementById('points');
    lifes.innerHTML = 3;
    points.innerHTML = 0;
    change_asteroid();
}

function change_asteroid(){
    const asteroids = document.querySelectorAll('.asteroid');
    const index  = Math.floor(Math.random() * asteroids.length);
    console.log(index);
    var time = Math.round(Math.random() * (3000, 1000) + 1000)
    asteroids[index].src = "reptilian.png";
    setTimeout(() => {
        asteroids[index].src = "asteroid.png";
        if (lifes == 0) {
            console.log("End");
        }else{
            change_asteroid();   
        }
    }, tiempo);
}

function punch(e){
    console.log(e);
}

let asteroids = document.querySelectorAll('.asteroid');
asteroids.forEach(asteroid => asteroid.addEventListener('click', punch))
```

For now, everything works okey but the problem is with the punch. I need to catch if the user clicked in reptilian before it changes to asteroid again.

Comment: `function punch() {console.log(this);}` see what you get.

Comment: In addition to the above comment, you can use the `Event` object: `event.target`

Comment: I don't get nothing @NiettheDarkAbsol

Comment: You can see the fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/761fmngb/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by checking the src-attribute of the clicked image (the target of the click event) for the word "alien".

```js
e.target.src.includes('alien')
```

**Working example**:

```js
function startGame(){
    //Aquí declaro las variables que voy a usar
    let lifes = document.getElementById('lifes');
    const points = document.getElementById('points');
    lifes.innerHTML = 3;
    points.innerHTML = 0;
    change_asteroid();
}

function change_asteroid(){
    const asteroids = document.querySelectorAll('.asteroid');
    const index  = Math.floor(Math.random() * asteroids.length);
    console.log(index);
    var time = Math.round(Math.random() * (3000, 1000) + 1000)
    asteroids[index].src = "https://img1.freepng.es/20180201/irq/kisspng-extraterrestrial-life-display-resolution-alien-5a7325c8251a59.091383891517495752152.jpg";
    setTimeout(() => {
        asteroids[index].src = "https://img2.freepng.es/20180205/bdw/kisspng-asteroid-belt-clip-art-asteroid-png-clipart-5a77e944307e54.3628452215178079401986.jpg";
        if (lifes == 0) {
            console.log("End");
        }else{
            change_asteroid();   
        }
    }, 3000);
}

function punch(e){
    var alien = e.target.src.includes('alien');
    console.log(alien);
    const points = document.getElementById('points');
    points.innerHTML = parseInt(points.textContent) + 1;
}

let asteroids = document.querySelectorAll('.asteroid');
asteroids.forEach(asteroid => asteroid.addEventListener('click', punch))
```

```css
main{
    text-align: center;
    align-content: center;
}
#superior p{
    display: block;
}
img{
    width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<main>
    <div id="top">
        <p class="blue_button" id="points">points</p>
        <p id="beauty_text">Whack-a-mole</p>
        <p class="blue_button" id="lifes">lifes</p>
    </div>
    <div id="meteors">
        <img src="https://img2.freepng.es/20180205/bdw/kisspng-asteroid-belt-clip-art-asteroid-png-clipart-5a77e944307e54.3628452215178079401986.jpg" class="asteroid">
        <img src="https://img2.freepng.es/20180205/bdw/kisspng-asteroid-belt-clip-art-asteroid-png-clipart-5a77e944307e54.3628452215178079401986.jpg" class="asteroid">
        <img src="https://img2.freepng.es/20180205/bdw/kisspng-asteroid-belt-clip-art-asteroid-png-clipart-5a77e944307e54.3628452215178079401986.jpg" class="asteroid">
        <br>
        <img src="https://img2.freepng.es/20180205/bdw/kisspng-asteroid-belt-clip-art-asteroid-png-clipart-5a77e944307e54.3628452215178079401986.jpg" class="asteroid">
        <img src="https://img2.freepng.es/20180205/bdw/kisspng-asteroid-belt-clip-art-asteroid-png-clipart-5a77e944307e54.3628452215178079401986.jpg" class="asteroid">
    </div>
    <div>
        <button class="blue_button" onclick="startGame();">Start</button>
    </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 2):

As you can see in `console.log` punch work perfectly

```js
function startGame(){
    //Aquí declaro las variables que voy a usar
    let lifes = document.getElementById('lifes');
    const points = document.getElementById('points');
    lifes.innerHTML = 3;
    points.innerHTML = 0;
    change_asteroid();
}

function change_asteroid(){
    const asteroids = document.querySelectorAll('.asteroid');
    const index  = Math.floor(Math.random() * asteroids.length);
    console.log(index);
    var time = Math.round(Math.random() * (3000, 1000) + 1000)
    asteroids[index].src = "https://img1.freepng.es/20180201/irq/kisspng-extraterrestrial-life-display-resolution-alien-5a7325c8251a59.091383891517495752152.jpg";
    setTimeout(() => {
        asteroids[index].src = "https://img2.freepng.es/20180205/bdw/kisspng-asteroid-belt-clip-art-asteroid-png-clipart-5a77e944307e54.3628452215178079401986.jpg";
        if (lifes == 0) {
            console.log("End");
        }else{
            change_asteroid();   
        }
    }, 3000);
}

function punch(e){
    console.log('punched');
}

let asteroids = document.querySelectorAll('.asteroid');
asteroids.forEach(asteroid => asteroid.addEventListener('click', punch))
```

```css
main{
    text-align: center;
    align-content: center;
}
#superior p{
    display: block;
}
img{
    width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<main>
        <div id="top">
            <p class="blue_button" id="points">points</p>
            <p id="beauty_text">Whack-a-mole</p>
            <p class="blue_button" id="lifes">lifes</p>
        </div>
        <div id="meteors">
            <img src="https://img2.freepng.es/20180205/bdw/kisspng-asteroid-belt-clip-art-asteroid-png-clipart-5a77e944307e54.3628452215178079401986.jpg" class="asteroid">
            <img src="https://img2.freepng.es/20180205/bdw/kisspng-asteroid-belt-clip-art-asteroid-png-clipart-5a77e944307e54.3628452215178079401986.jpg" class="asteroid">
            <img src="https://img2.freepng.es/20180205/bdw/kisspng-asteroid-belt-clip-art-asteroid-png-clipart-5a77e944307e54.3628452215178079401986.jpg" class="asteroid">
            <br>
            <img src="https://img2.freepng.es/20180205/bdw/kisspng-asteroid-belt-clip-art-asteroid-png-clipart-5a77e944307e54.3628452215178079401986.jpg" class="asteroid">
            <img src="https://img2.freepng.es/20180205/bdw/kisspng-asteroid-belt-clip-art-asteroid-png-clipart-5a77e944307e54.3628452215178079401986.jpg" class="asteroid">
        </div>
        <div>
            <button class="blue_button" onclick="startGame();">Start</button>
        </div>
    </main>
```

You can use `e.target` for see which target is "punched" (i add an example alien `+1` and asteroid `-1` points)

```js
function startGame(){
    //Aquí declaro las variables que voy a usar
    let lifes = document.getElementById('lifes');
    const points = document.getElementById('points');
    lifes.innerHTML = 3;
    points.innerHTML = 0;
    change_asteroid();
}

function change_asteroid(){
    const asteroids = document.querySelectorAll('.asteroid');
    const index  = Math.floor(Math.random() * asteroids.length);
    console.log(index);
    var time = Math.round(Math.random() * (3000, 1000) + 1000)
    asteroids[index].src = "https://img1.freepng.es/20180201/irq/kisspng-extraterrestrial-life-display-resolution-alien-5a7325c8251a59.091383891517495752152.jpg";
    asteroids[index].classList.toggle("asteroid");
    setTimeout(() => {
        asteroids[index].classList.toggle("asteroid");
        asteroids[index].src = "https://img2.freepng.es/20180205/bdw/kisspng-asteroid-belt-clip-art-asteroid-png-clipart-5a77e944307e54.3628452215178079401986.jpg";
        if (lifes == 0) {
            console.log("End");
        }else{
            change_asteroid();   
        }
    }, 3000);
}

function punch(e){
    if(e.target.classList.contains('asteroid')){
      console.log('asteroid punch -1 points');
    }else{
      console.log('alien punch +1 points');
    }
}

let asteroids = document.querySelectorAll('.asteroid');
asteroids.forEach(asteroid => asteroid.addEventListener('click', punch))
```

```css
main{
    text-align: center;
    align-content: center;
}
#superior p{
    display: block;
}
img{
    width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<main>
        <div id="top">
            <p class="blue_button" id="points">points</p>
            <p id="beauty_text">Whack-a-mole</p>
            <p class="blue_button" id="lifes">lifes</p>
        </div>
        <div id="meteors">
            <img src="https://img2.freepng.es/20180205/bdw/kisspng-asteroid-belt-clip-art-asteroid-png-clipart-5a77e944307e54.3628452215178079401986.jpg" class="asteroid">
            <img src="https://img2.freepng.es/20180205/bdw/kisspng-asteroid-belt-clip-art-asteroid-png-clipart-5a77e944307e54.3628452215178079401986.jpg" class="asteroid">
            <img src="https://img2.freepng.es/20180205/bdw/kisspng-asteroid-belt-clip-art-asteroid-png-clipart-5a77e944307e54.3628452215178079401986.jpg" class="asteroid">
            <br>
            <img src="https://img2.freepng.es/20180205/bdw/kisspng-asteroid-belt-clip-art-asteroid-png-clipart-5a77e944307e54.3628452215178079401986.jpg" class="asteroid">
            <img src="https://img2.freepng.es/20180205/bdw/kisspng-asteroid-belt-clip-art-asteroid-png-clipart-5a77e944307e54.3628452215178079401986.jpg" class="asteroid">
        </div>
        <div>
            <button class="blue_button" onclick="startGame();">Start</button>
        </div>
    </main>
```